# How to render a "github_document" Rmd without generating the HTML preview?

Tags: r, r-markdown, render

I'm maintaining a package and have to rebuild the `README.Rmd` file every once in a while.

Using the "knit" button in RStudio, the effect is correct: the file `README.md` is generated at the root of the package, and a `README.html` preview is created in a temporary file and opened.

However, if I use the following command, the HTML preview is created at the root of the package, which is unnecessary.

```r
rmarkdown::render(input="README.Rmd")
```

**How to tell this preview file to be temporary, or even to not bother to exist at all?**

I tried to set `intermediates_dir=tempfile()` with no effect, and I couldn't find what command RStudio is running on "knit" push. Moreover, it seems that this simple command does not have this side effect when run through Github Actions ([link](https://github.com/r-lib/actions/tree/v2-branch/examples#render-rmarkdown)).

**PS:** Here is a minimal example of my `Rmarkdown` file (whole file [here](https://github.com/DanChaltiel/crosstable)):

```
---
  output: github_document
---

Hello Word
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `html_preview` option to `false`, like so:

```markdown
---
output:
  github_document:
    html_preview: false
---

Hello World
```

This option is documented [here](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/github_document_format.html). BTW, I suspect that a `.html` file *is* generated on the server where the `render-rmarkdown` [action](https://github.com/r-lib/actions/tree/v2-branch/examples#render-rmarkdown) is performed; you don't see it locally because the action only commits changes to `.md` files:

```sh
$ git commit ${RMD_PATH[*]/.Rmd/.md} -m 'Re-build Rmarkdown files' || echo "No changes to commit"
```